# How to summon an invisible falling block in minecraft 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon an invisible falling block using a repeating command block to get rid of the shadow created by it, I've tried using ActiveEffects NBT but that isn't seeming to work, here's the code:

```
summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~1.5 ~ {BlockState:{Name:"barrier"},Time:0,NoGravity:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:1,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever the shadow is, set it to barrier, then summon another falling block at the location of the barrier that the block originally was.

Comment: Thanks, never realised you can do this!

Answer (score -1):

Since the block is an entity, can you not just give it the Invisibility effect?

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. Most inanimate objects like falling blocks are actually immune to effects.